# remove '\' from string api response aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, aws-lambda

I am have AWS Lambda function where I am sending a string as my final response

```
 let abc= `"phone_exist":"0","calls":"0","lastaction":"0"`
 callback(null,abc);
```

**Output: "\"phone_exist\":\"0\",\"calls\":\"0\",\"lastaction\":\"0\""**

here I am unable to understand why "\" has been appended in my string.

1. Can anyone explain me the reason behind this?
2. Is their a way using which '\' can be removed so I can get in following form

   **"phone_exist"="1","calls"="2","lastaction"="3"**

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character used to escape `"`. A simple way to get rid of `\ ` is to add `{}` at the beginning and the and of the string and use `JSON.parse(output)`. This will convert the result into an object and you can use it directly using `calls = output.calls`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a string, not an object, so Lambda is encoding your string as JSON.  What you actually want is most likely this:

```
let abc = { "phone_exist":"0","calls":"0","lastaction":"0" };
callback(null,abc);
```

Since those are numbers, you may not want to quote them.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash(\) is an escape character for the special character Double Quote(").

Remove them(") from your original string...

Or ignore them as they are just escape characters.